# How to make complex bifurcation diagrams

Tags: functional-analysis, dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I am wondering if anyone here can direct me to a method or software resource that can be used for developing high quality bifurcation diagrams.  The bifurcation diagram I am trying to develop is very complex, and unfortunately the function that generates it is quite abstract so I do not have some recursive function available to use in developing it.  I can give the software both the location of each periodic point on the interval and the parameter values where the system snaps into a different stable periodic orbit.

Would any of you happen to have any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: If you have only numerical data of this kind and no equations, I think no specific well-known bifurcation software will help you. It's much easier to visualize your data using any plotting library that you know. For example, if you have one parameter and a mapping of the interval, you can visualize attraction basins depending on that parameter. Make a color plot "$x$ vs parameter value" and color point $(x_0, r_0)$ with some color corresponding to its attractor for parameter value $r_0$.